# scientific transliteration - spelling - pesah vs pesach? (who spells it pessah?)

Tags: spelling-variants

we're all familiar with the spelling pesach. But I recently saw the word Pessah, I guess a name.

I know there's the scientific transliteration that replaces chet with 'h' rather than 'ch'.

But in the scientific transliteration i'd have thought pesach would be more like pesah.

Almost everybody I know spells it Pesach.

Who spells it pessah? and who spells it pesah?

Is one of them(pessah? pesah?) a common sephardi spelling ('cos sephardi pronunciation pronounces the chet less of a ch)

is one of them the scientific transliteration? or close to the scientific transliteration?

Comment: What do you mean "scientific"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems unrelated to any Jewish topic. Clarify the question context.

Comment: @DanF you're not aware jews have a language called hebrew that judaism considers holy/special? and that hebrew can be written with english letters, and there are conventions and in academic circles even a standard way

Comment: @DanF, I would argue it is on topic because it is about how to express a Jewish name or a Jewish holiday in English and writing about Jewish holidays is a Jewish practice. Barlop, The fact that is about Hebrew does not make it on topic unless it relates to Judaism, whatever Judaism thinks of Hebrew.

Comment: ...to my eyes Pessah would be a valid English spelling of "Pesach" if there was a dot under the "h"...instead of the "ch" we're used to seeing. I think it's probably spelled with the "ch" these days more often because it uses standard keyboard characters...oh DUH wait a minute, my sister's first Hebrew name is Pessah, representing Peh-sin-hey...!

Comment: @Gary u write " Peh-sin-hey.." Are you sure about your sister's name?(or is she sure?!) Look at Exodus 12:27 Pesach is spelt with a Samech not a Sin.You're right re dot below the h rather than a ch(that - just h, with dot below it, would be scientific transliteration for chet/het  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B8%A4  ). I'm aware of h like that in scientific transliteration. The issue is the number of 's'. But on a related note, there's no dagesh dot in the samech. A dagesh in a samech would mean a double letter and would I suppose justify two 's' but it's not.

Comment: barlop -- There is a Yiddish girl's name "Pessah," that may or may not be related to פסח. (I don't know if it is or is not) [ cc @Gary ]

Comment: Well, I guess [it is](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47660/5323), after all [ cc @Gary ]

Comment: Syrian Sefardim

Comment: regarding on/off topic, What if it's a hebrew question where pronunciation relevant to leining?  And what if it's something the RaDaK has said regarding regarding pronunciation?  What if it's something regarding different preserved traditions of pronunciation? What if it's a question of how an old ashkenazi community insisted was the true G-d given Torah pronunciation of a vowel.

Comment: I saw a french product that said "cacher le pessah" it's quite a common spelling(for passover/pesach) in france I suppose, don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that the name that you saw is a Yiddish name called פעשע or פעשא. [For example](http://www.amitys.com/webtrees/individual.php?pid=I6765&ged=Gedcom.ged). It is [Yiddish for Passover](http://www.kveller.com/jewish_names/display.php?n=Pesha&k=1199) and used as a girl's name.

Although a more typical transliteration would be Pesche, you certainly see anglicized versions of a Shin as a double ss.

Or, it could have been a french transliteration of Pesach (or come through french). [For example](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessa'h).

Pesach (the holiday in Hebrew) is typically a boys name and more typically Sefardi (although it is common enough for ashkenazim). Pesche is a girls name and (obviously) Ashkenazi.

Comment: I know plenty of Ashkenazi people named Pesach

Comment: +1 for pointing out it could be Yiddish. I am reminded of the Sholem Aleichem character Peysi, the deceased father from מאָטל פּייסי דעם חזנס" כתבֿים   פֿון אַ ייִנגל אַ יתום Motl Peysi dem khazns; ksovim fun a yingl a yosem (Motl, Pessi the Cantor's Son)."  Can be found in Yiddish [here](https://archive.org/stream/nybc210810#4)

Comment: hmm, yiddish for passover. I know they pronounce some vowels differently in yiddish to hebrew.. but that has different letters too. I guess they came up with another word for pesach For example, Yaakuv is yiddish for Yaakov. sucus is yiddish for succot/succose. but for succus and yaakuv they didn't change the spelling, they just pronounced the cholam differently.

Comment: Your link `Yiddish for Passover` doesn't corroborate your claim. It'd be worth checking Alexander Beider's dictionary of Ashkenazic given names.

Comment: @magicker72 it used it https://web.archive.org/web/20111205091955/http://www.kveller.com/jewish_names/display.php?n=Pesha&k=1199